# False parameter estimates with NLS in R - why is this the case?

Tags: r, parameters, nls

I am trying to fit two sales diffusion models on sales data of two consecutive product generations. Ultimately, I need to fit the models to determine the optimal launch timing of the second product generation, retrospectively. The models are defined as follows: [Models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrf7Y.jpg), where F(t) is: [F(t)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKVRC.png), s1 is the sales of the first product generation, s2 is the sales of the second product generation, and Tau2 is the introduction time of the second product generation. M1, M2, q_g and p_q are the parameters that need to be estimated. M1, q_g and p_q are assumed to be shared by the two product generations. I thus use nls to joinly estimate M1, M2, q_g and p_q.

The problem arise in the regression results, that yield the following:

```
Parameters:
    Estimate       Std. Error      t value             Pr(>|t|)    
M1 57272.955000  5132.566387  11.159 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
M2 65083.042585  9151.330507   7.112      0.0000000000872 ***
P      0.043177     0.003957  10.913 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
Q     -0.082847     0.007974 -10.390 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Residual standard error: 3487 on 121 degrees of freedom
Number of iterations to convergence: 10 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 0.000002792
```

By definition, all estimated parameters should be >0, and in my results, q is negative. I have tried adding lower bounds to the parameter estimates of 0, but this just yields q = 0, which I also believe is wrong.

I thus wonder if I am providing inputs that are not feasible for NLS - in particular the way I am assigning the time variables to the model. Please find the data and code that I am executing.

Any inputs to if I am doing it wrong - and how to resolve it - would be highly appreciated.

```
s1 <- c(885.0,780.0,14610.0,13035.0,10395.0,12390.0,16260.0,14550.0,13073.0,19639.5,12675.0,15870.0,18615.0,17231.0,16159.0,19500.0,18135.0,13845.0,20175.0,18210.0,22110.0,17925.0,13770.0,17040.0,18076.5,23008.5,18270.0,20820.0,19275.0,22140.0,21300.0,22350.0,22185.0,24495.0,19605.0,21945.0,18855.0,26340.0,28515.0,26190.0,23895.0,29700.0,30525.0,28740.0,30930.0,25875.0,27720.0,29895.0,28710.0,30060.0,31485.0,30435.0,32730.0,33525.0,31725.0,32325.0,35580.0,34230.0,22380.0,28440.0,21225.0,24765.0,26520.0,21180.0,25260.0,21975.0,22455.0,29805.0,19185.0,20850.0,16170.0,20265.0,19500.0,20000.0,19450.0,18950.0,20500.0,18750.0,18649.5,17000.0,16000.0,16700.0,17500.0,16000.0,15900.0,15650.0,15250.0,15000.0,14500.0,14550.0)
s2.new <- c(2025.0,7077.5,12660.0,14235.0,23115.0,18180.0,25680.0,27210.0,25740.0,27120.0,28725.0,27435.0,35550.0,28635.0,34440.0,29160.0,34500.0,36100.0,35650.0,36500.0,36700.0,36250.0,37100.0,39000.0,37000.0,37500.0,39500.0,40000.0,39000.0,38500.0,39500.0,38750.0,38000.0,37900.0,34500.0)

S <- c(s1, s2.new)

T<-1:90
Tau2<-56 

T.new<-c(56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90)

T2.new<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35)  

fo12 <- S ~ c(M1*((1-exp(-(P+Q)*T))/((Q/P)*exp(-(P+Q)*T)+1))*
                  ifelse((T-Tau2)>=0,(1-((1-exp(-(P+Q)*(T-Tau2)))/((Q/P)*exp(-(P+Q)*(T-Tau2))+1))),1),

                  (M2 + M1*((1-exp(-(P+Q)*T.new))/((Q/P)*exp(-(P+Q)*T.new)+1)))*
                  ((1-exp(-(P+Q)*T2.new))/((Q/P)*exp(-(P+Q)*T2.new)+1)))

S.func <- nls(fo12, start= c(list(M1=sum(s1), M2=100000, P=0.01, Q=0.001)))
summary(S.func)
```

Comment: Although this is not likely the source of the problem, suggest you use something other than `T` since `T` is used for TRUE in R.  If the solution you get is a good fit (try plotting the points and overplotting with the fit) If that looks like a good fit you may simply be wrong about the model not fitting.  Another possibility is that there are multiple local optima iand you are simply not getting the one you want.  In that case you will need to try different starting values. The nls2 package can be used to run from multiple starting values.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I really appreciate it. When plotting points versus the fit, it looks good. Maybe you are right that it is fitted correctly.  It is an interesting hypothesis in regards to multiple local optima.  I will try the nls2 package as you suggest. Once again, thank you.